# How to create n copies of every row on dataframe based value in list Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe

```
| Domain   | Description 
| test.com | some string
.....
```

I have a text augmentation algorithm which accepts a string as input and returns list with `10` modified strings. Let's call this function `def augmentation(text)`

For every row in dataframe, i want to make augmentation to `Description` column and create 10 copy of each row and pass values from `augmentation` function to `Description`.
The expected result should looks something like:

```
| Domain   | Description 
| test.com | some string
| test.com | smoe string
| test.com | moe sring
| test.com | some sring
..... and so on.
```

Comment: try: `df=df.reindex(df.index.repeat(10)).reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but in your approach it creates 10 copies of row, but in my case i want to pass function augmentation like apply and creates n rows based on every value from returned list from this function

Answer (score 0):

I came up with following

```
df['Description'] = df['Description'].apply(augmentation)
result = df.assign(Description=df['Description']).explode('Description').reset_index(drop=True)
```